# How do i recreate a loading truck case with a limited number of trucks?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a warehouse with many palletrack which contains raw materials that have to be loaded on trucks and moved to a second warehouse. The loading zones (where trucks are loaded) are the green rectangular nodes (see image). The problem is that I don't know how to recreate the loading. If I use a seize then every single agent will seize a truck, but if I used the pickup block (like the pickup model tutorial), the source would create more trucks than I want(they are limited).
Any tips? (i want to say thanks to all the people who are helping me this week by the way)

[image: pickup case]

[image: network]

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many ways to model this I think the best option would be to batch your agents into truckloads and then to seize the trucks. Trucks must live inside a resource pool, so that you can have a fixed number of trucks.

Since you are using a network model I would then suggest you attach the truck to the batch you created and move it around and then detach the truck and release it afterward. You can however simply seize the truck and have the batch object use the animation of a truck.

[image]

Comment: i think that if i used this model than i would not have a real time of loading because the forklift operator works only with the batch agent instead of every single raw material.

Comment: You will need to simulate this delay before the actual batch process. If you need to ensure that the forklift operator only loads that which is required for the batch you need to make use of a wait block and remove only the agents that are needed to create the batch, then simulate the delay, and then batch them. But this seems like a separate question.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242424/4019094